# Limit Theorem -- reason for this requirement?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following statement in my textbook:

> If $r > 0$ is a rational number, then 
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^r} = 0 $$

The book does not explain why we have the requirement that $r$ is rational. Why must this be the case?

Comment: Could be they first prove for integers, then rationals, then reals. At each step, you can use the previous result to prove the next one.

Comment: To elabrotate a bit, it's true that it hold for all positive real numbers. But in order to show that, it is useful to first explicitly claim and show that it holds for positive rational numbers.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: The symbol $x^{r} $ can be defined (to some extent) using algebra when $r$ is rational. Dealing with this symbol when $r$ is irrational is altogether a different ballgame and your book perhaps prefers to follow the intellectually honest approach of highlighting the difference between these two cases.